# HTML Download attribute of <a> tag

Tags: html

I'm using following code for making a pdf file downloadable

```
<a href="E:\NetBeans Project\Online Examination System\web\Syllabus\FT Syllabus.pdf" download style="color:black;">Click Here</a>
```

but when I click to download error I'm getting an error "Failed - Network error"

Comment: The path is local. Is your page local as well?

Comment: Add `file://` prefix :)

Comment: yes, my page is also local

Answer (score 0):

Rename **FT Syllabus** to **FTSyllabus** as spaces cannot be there in Links and try this code. This may give you a solution

```
<a href="E:\NetBeans Project\Online Examination System\web\Syllabus\FTSyllabus.pdf" download="Syllabus" style="color:black;">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2362501/michael) is right. You just need to add the `file:\\` prefix.

Like

```
<a href="file:\\E:\NetBeans Project\Online Examination System\web\Syllabus\FT Syllabus.pdf" download style="color:black;">Click Here</a>
```

Some browsers will sometimes treat local paths like yours

```
<a href="E:\NetBeans Project\Online Examination System\web\Syllabus\FT Syllabus.pdf" download style="color:black;">Click Here</a>
```

as if they had the `file:\\` prefix even if it isn't actually there.

But it seems that it is not the case with your browser.

Giving a value to the `download` attribute is [optional](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_a_download.asp). If a value is given, the file will be downloaded with that name instead of its original name.